# PowerShell script to get site collection administrators, site owners in SharePoint 2013 CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, powershell, csom, pnp-powershell

i want PowerShell script for SharePoint 2013 CSOM to get below details

1. site collection administrators
2. site owners
3. Site is multilingual or not

Please assist.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PowerShell command as below:

```
$Site = Get-SPSite "http://spsite"
$Site.RootWeb.SiteAdministrators | Select DisplayName, Email
$Site.Owner | Select DisplayName, Email
$site.RootWeb.IsMultiLingual
```

Comment: i want CSOM script for that